# How do I find the limit of this problem?

Tags: calculus

I'm supposed to find the limit of $\arctan(x^2)$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$. I was thinking that infinity could be plugged into arctan(x^2) and the answer would be infinity, but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: In general you cannot safely plug in infinity to find a limit and in this case, even if you did, there is good reason to believe that the arctangent would not be infinite.  Think about the graph of the tangent function. Try $\arctan(1000000^2)$ on your calculator.

Comment: That doesn't count. See http://www.math-atlas.org/99/calc_errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi/2}\tan(x)=\infty.$$

Comment: So the limit of arctan would be pi/2 due to tan's limit being infinite?

Comment: That's the right conclusion, yes.

Comment: So whenever I have x approaching A for an arctan that equals B, the inverse would always be tan = A as x approaches B?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (Provided that $\arctan$ is the inverse of $\tan$ restricted to the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ as usual).

Comment: The limit is with $x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2} ^- $ hence will be equal to $+\infty$

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I dont get how did you conclude the limit of $\text{arctan}x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $x\to\infty.$ I know that tan is an increasing function, but I dont get this?

Answer (score 2):

For infinitely large values of $x$ $$\tan ^{-1}\left(x^2\right)\simeq \frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{3
   x^6}-\frac{1}{5 x^{10}}+\frac{1}{7
   x^{14}}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{16}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The arctan is the inverse of the tan on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Given this knowledge, what's is the limit of arctan(x) to infinity?